# Android FIDO2 throwing vague errors

Tags: android, authentication, webauthn, fido

I am trying to implement FIDO2 on Android. I have the assetlinks.json hosted on my domain (Sorry I don't want and not sure if I'm allowed to reveal the whole url yet).
I have the assets_statements string defined and added it to my Manifest and I also implemented the whole get register challenge logic where I am creating a pending intent from PublicKeyCredentialCreateOptions.
After I launch the intent I see a white screen which shows up and closes really fast without any descriptive error or anything and I have no idea how to debug this issue. The log shows:

```
ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.google.android.gms/.fido.fido2.ui.Fido2FullScreenActivity
E/Fido: [DigitalAssetsAssociationChecker] JSON Object doesn't have linked key
E/Fido: [Fido2RequestController] The incoming request cannot be validated
E/Fido: [Fido2RequestController] The incoming request cannot be validated
```

On https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator it says that my domain grants app deeplinking to my package name.

I am using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-fido:18.1.0`

The errors in the log are not helpful in any way and I'm not sure if I am still missing something here, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I figured it out by playing with the example app https://github.com/googlecodelabs/fido2-codelab and changing things around, so I'm going to answer my own question.
When requesting a registration challenge the RP.id field needs to be the same as your domain name.
On the sample the Rp.id value is "webauthn-codelab.glitch.me", I changed it to "webauthn.glitch.me" just to try out what would happen. Guess what, I'm getting the same errors as before:

```
E/Fido: [DigitalAssetsAssociationChecker] JSON Object doesn't have linked key
E/Fido: [Fido2RequestController] The incoming request cannot be validated
E/Fido: [Fido2RequestController] The incoming request cannot be validated
```

To conclude, be sure that the RP.id that get's returned from backend matches the domain url.
Also here is a link explaining RP id: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#relying-party-identifier

Answer (score 1):

Another reason that this error can appear: if the relation `delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls` is missing from the assetlinks.json, Android devices may reject the association with the error above.

So for example the following assetlinks (which I've copied straight out of the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/passkeys#add-support-dal)) will be rejected with the above error:

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "web",
    "site": "https://signin.example.com"
  }
 },
 {
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [SHA_HEX_VALUE]
  }
 }]
```

The solution in my case was to add the `handle_all_urls` relation:

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls", "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "web",
    "site": "https://signin.example.com"
  }
 },
 {
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls", "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [SHA_HEX_VALUE]
  }
 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

So same symptom.

In my case, the issue was I was trying to host the assetlinks.json file on an internal dev server.

This does NOT work.

The assetlinks.json file MUST be hosted on a server publicly accessible to google's servers.

Answer (score -1):

Got the same error `JSON Object doesn't have linked key` on `Fido2ApiClient.getSignPendingIntent()` call.
The solution for my case was to set real user key (aka id) in `allowList`.

Comment: this answer isn't helpful as it lacks detail.